# ES5 utility functions implementations

Tags: javascript

I have a small library for utility functions for ES5 mainly aimed at OO code organization.

Are there any recommendations for the API or for the code quality / organization?

- [github page](https://github.com/Raynos/pd/blob/master/lib/pd.js)
- [styleGuide it complies to](https://github.com/Raynos/pd/blob/master/docs/styleGuide.md)

Note the library has a few tricks in it for aggressive minification.

#### Code inlined

```
/*
    pd(obj) -> propertyDescriptorsOfObject {
        bindAll: function that binds all the methods of an object to the object,
        extend: function that extends the first argument with the rest
        Name: returns a namespace(anyKey) -> uniqueObject function
    }

    pd requires ES5. Uses the shimmable subset of ES5.
*/
(function (Object, slice) {
    "use strict";

    extend(pd, {
        bindAll: bindAll,
        extend: extend,
        Name: Name
    });

    typeof window !== "undefined" ? window.pd = pd : module.exports = pd;

    /*
        pd will return all the own propertydescriptors of the object

        @param Object object - object to get pds from.

        @return Object - A hash of key/propertyDescriptors
    */    
    function pd(obj, retObj) {
        retObj = {};
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function(key) {
            var pd = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key);
            retObj[key] = pd;
        });
        return retObj;
    }

    /*
        Extend will extend the firat parameter with any other parameters 
        passed in. Only the own property names will be extended into
        the object

        @param Object target - target to be extended
        @arguments Array [target, ...] - the rest of the objects passed
            in will extended into the target

        @return Object - the target
    */
    function extend(target) {
        slice.call(arguments, 1).forEach(function(source) {
            Object.defineProperties(target, pd(source));
        });
        return target;
    }

    /*
        defines a namespace object. This hides a "privates" object on object 
        under the "key" namespace

        @param Object object - object to hide a privates object on
        @param Object key - key to hide it under

        @author Gozala : https://gist.github.com/1269991

        @return Object privates
    */
    function namespace(object, key) {
        var privates = Object.create(object),
            valueOf = object.valueOf;

        Object.defineProperty(object, "valueOf", {
            value: function(value) {
                return value !== key ? valueOf.apply(this, arguments) : privates;
            },
            writable: true
        });

        return privates;
    }

    /*
        Constructs a Name function, when given an object it will return a
        privates object. 

        @author Gozala : https://gist.github.com/1269991

        @return Function name
    */
    function Name(key) {
        key = {};
        return name;

        function name(object) {
            var privates = object.valueOf(key);
            return privates !== object ? privates : namespace(object, key)
        }
    }

    /*
        bindAll binds all methods to have their context set to the object

        @param Object obj - the object to bind methods on
        @param Array whitelist - optional whitelist of methods to bind

        @return Object - the bound object
    */
    function bindAll(obj, whitelist) {
        (whitelist || Object.keys(obj).filter(getMethods)).forEach(bindMethods);

        return obj;

        function getMethods(key) {
            return obj[key].call;
        }

        function bindMethods(name) {
            obj[name] = obj[name].bind(obj)
        }
    }   
})(Object, [].slice);
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything majorly wrong, so these will be mostly minor things.

`getMethods` doesn't really get methods, `isMethod` (or `isBindable`) is a more descriptive name for it.

You'd also want to check that `.call` is in fact the `.call` inherited from Function
prototype, or since you are doing the filtering in preparation for `.bind`, just
check that `obj[key].bind === Function.prototype.bind` or similar. Also check for truthiness, so you don't try to access `null.bind`:

`return obj[key] && obj[key].bind ===`

If `Name` is a normal function, it shouldn't be capitalized and be a named like a *noun*,
this is convention for functions that are meant to be invoked as constructors using `new`.
Something like `makeName` or `makeNamespace`, a *verb* that implies a factory, would
be a better fit.

Comment: `isMethod` and `.bind === Function.prototype.bind` are indeed issues, I've handled those. As for the `pd.Name` name, not sure how to handle that. I don't like `makeName` it'll be either `pd.name` or `pd.Name`